# Dúvida Socket.io Notificação Push

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, socket.io

Olá, tenho uma aplicação feita com node.js e socket.io que envia uma notificação push quando a pagina cliente.html está aberta. a minha dúvida é: Como enviar e receber a notificação mesmo que a página do cliente.html esteja fechada.

Quando a pagina cliente.html esta aberta e envio uma notificação eu recebo dessa forma --> http://prntscr.com/jpgzfv

então, gostaria de receber essa notificacao mesmo que o usuario não esteja com a página cliente.html aberta.

alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso com socket.io ?

Comment: Vai receber no celular? No pager? Sinal de fumaça? Se ele não está na sua página, ele vai estar onde? Qual é o cliente da sua notificação, se ele não está utilizando o cliente padrão?